# Error : Variable used within its own initial value with type(of:) function

Tags: swift, swift4.1

In Swift standard [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type) by Apple :

```
func printInfo(_ value: Any) {
   let type = type(of: value)
   print("'\(value)' of type '\(type)'")
}
```

and it give an error : **Variable used within its own initial value**

[image]

How can I fix this with Swift 4.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a documentation error. The function used to be `typeOf`. Recent version (can't remember which one) renamed it to `type`. The compiler is getting confused between `type` the local variable and `type` the function in Swift's Standard Library.

Use a different name for your local variable:

```
func printInfo(_ value: Any) {
   let t = type(of: value)
   print("'\(value)' of type '\(t)'")
}
```

Or explicitly refer to the function:

```
func printInfo(_ value: Any) {
   let type = Swift.type(of: value)
   print("'\(value)' of type '\(type)'")
}
```